# Can't submit OpenGraph action

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Created an OpenGraph action and object. Trying to submit my action. When I click on `Submit`, a popup appears with 3 steps. I can do the first step without any problems. But when I try to submit the second step, it doesn't do anything. i.e. it doesn't move onto step 3.

When I inspect via Firebug, it says:

```
NetworkError: 500
Sorry, something went wrong.
We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.
```

Comment: What are the remaining steps? I've found the developers subdomain very crashy in Chrome and so I've started using IE for everything developers.facebook.com

Comment: I can get through `1) Provide trigger steps`. When I click the next button on `2) Request optional properties`, it just hangs. It's supposed to send me to `3) Review Submission`. I'm on a Mac. Tried with FF 11.0 and Chrome 18.0.1025.142

Comment: Tried with Chrome and with IE on another computer. Same issue.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're doing anything wrong. Over the past two days I've been getting a really intermittent service from the developers site. Recently I noticed it all seems to work in IE. (Which would suggest I should delete my cache & cookies etc from Chrome but that didn't help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/330108297036705

Apparently resolved. :)

Comment: Still not resolved for me! It hasn't worked for me for almost a month!

Comment: Still a problem: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/113025105498047?browse=search_4f7fc6186822c9d25736770